# list of integers where the mean, median, mode and IQR are equal the the number of integers

Tags: statistics

I have been given a question in a maths assignment that I cannot seem to figure out can someone please help me the question is:

Explain how you could generate a list of **n** integers where the mean, median, mode and inter-quartile range are all equal to **n**

Thanks,

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I figured out that 1,1,7,7,7,8,18 works for when n = 7 but i dont know how to make it so that it works for all numbers @PHPirate

Comment: What definition of the first and third quartiles are you using? There is no agreement on how they're defined.

Comment: This kind of exercise, stressing the arithmetical properties of various descriptive statistics, seems popular in AP statistics courses and some elementary texts. They may be reasonable for drill if the purpose is mainly mathematical, but my opinion is that they have very little to do with building intuition toward the practice of statistics. Nevertheless, I'm giving an Answer.

Comment: @LachlanMinion: The IQR of your example is 3.5, according to at least one of several popular methods of defining quantiles. But the numbers could be rescaled outward from 7 on both sides to give any desired IQR. In R, `IQR(c(1,1,7,7,7,8,18))` returns 3.5. It is an interesting example because mean=median and it is _not_ symmetrical.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible for all $n$ (e.g., try your best for $n=2$).
But here is a strategy for sufficiently large $n$:

- In order to satisfy the median IQR condition, we intend to end up with $Q_1=\lfloor n/2\rfloor$, $Q_2=n$, $Q_3=Q_1+n$. We assign at least one data point to each of these
- In order to satisfy the mode condition, we assign a second data point to value $n$ and intend not to have any duplicate data points beyond that

Now we have almost painted ourselves into a corner. The conditions so far prescribe exactly, how many additional data points $x$ we need for which $x<Q_1$ holds, or $Q_1<x<Q_2$ holds, or $Q_2<x<Q_3$ holds, or $Q_3<x$ holds.
However, the rule to avoid duplicates restricts how many are allowed in each of these interval. But if I'm not mistaken, there is in fact just enough room even in the second and third quartile (if I'm wrong, just add a third data point at $n$ and allow duplicates).
So let's us fix the data point between $Q_1$ and $Q_3$ once and for all.

The only condition we have not met so far is that the mean should be $n$.
And to achieve this goal we are still allowed to play with the data points $<Q_1$ or $>Q_3$. And by increasing the maximal or the minimal data point we can achieve this as well.

Comment: This approach is a little different from mine, but I think no less interesting or valid.

Answer (score 1):

A sample of values symmetrical about $n$ will make the mean and median
both equal to $n$. Then adjust a few central values to make $n$ the mode.
If you really mean 'IQR' instead of the average of $Q_1$ and $Q_3$ you can re-scale the values
(while keeping $n$ at the 'center') to make the IQR almost anything you want.

Here is an example in R statistical software with $n = 20.$ (even integers
from 0 through 40 with 18 and 22 moved to replace 20, making a mode). The
idea generalizes to many other values of $n:$

```
 x = c(seq(0, 16, by = 2), rep(20, 2), seq(24, 40, by=2))
 length(x)
 [1] 20    # sample size
 mean(x)
 [1] 20
 median(x)
 [1] 20
 (quantile(x,.25)+quantile(x,.75))/2  # midway between quartiles
 25% 
 20 
 (min(x) + max(x))/2  # midrange
 [1] 20
 IQR(x)  # not exactly 20. re-scale as necessary
 [1] 21
 table(x)
 x
 0  2  4  6  8 10 12 14 16 20 24 26 28 30 32 34 36 38 40 
 1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1
```

The frequency distribution above shows that 20 (with a frequency of 2) is the mode.

The IQR for my example is 21 according to the method of finding quantiles in R. You can
adjust values inward a bit from 20 on either side to get any IQR you want
according to the rule you are using for quartiles.

*Note:* You may be surprised to discover that there are many different ways of
finding quartiles (and other quantiles). This is rarely discussed in
individual texts, each one pretending that its own definition is *the*
definition. If you have access to R software, you can type `? quantile` at
the prompt in the Session window to see definitions of nine methods
of finding quantiles. Each one is claimed to be 'best' for some particular
purpose.